# Handle Google authentication in FastAPI

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I am trying to implement a Google authentication on a FastAPI application.

I have a local register and login system with JWT that works perfectly, but the 'get_current_user' method depends on the oauth scheme for the local authentication:

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
credentials_exception = HTTPException(
    status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
    detail="Could not validate credentials",
    headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
)
try:
    payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    email: EmailStr = payload.get("sub")
    if email is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    token_data = TokenData(email=email)
except JWTError:
    raise credentials_exception
user = await User.find_one(User.email == EmailStr(token_data.email))
if user is None:
    raise credentials_exception
return user
```

oauth2_scheme using fastapi.security:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/jwt/login")
```

Now, the problem is that I don't know how to handle when a user is authenticated via Google, because I've defined a different Oauth client for Google:

```
google_oauth = OAuth(starlette_config)
google_oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url='https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'}
)
```

And my protected routes depend on the 'get_current_user' method, which is linked to the local oauth2_scheme.

**How should I go about allowing users who have logged in via Google to access my protected endpoints?**

Answer (score 0):

```py
from fastapi import Request, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials




class JWTBearer(HTTPBearer):
    def __init__(self, auto_error: bool = True):
        super(JWTBearer, self).__init__(auto_error=auto_error)

    async def __call__(self, request: Request):
        credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = await super(JWTBearer, self).__call__(request)
        if credentials:
            if not credentials.scheme == "Bearer":
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authentication scheme.")
            #if not self.verify_jwt(credentials.credentials):
            #    raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid token or expired token.")
            return credentials.credentials
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authorization code.")
```

now change your schema to

```py
oauth2_schema = JWTBearer()
```

This will give a new type of authorization that only accept jwt token instead of the normal password and username.

Process flow on swagger docs:

1. go to any of the endpoints that give you token
2. copy the token and click on the padlock icon,
3. paste the token then you are login.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).